# Inflating a file (more size)

Tags: image, file, size

I have an image which is of 21 KB.

I want to 'Inflate' the image so that it occupies 20MB or more. Is there any software or technique which can do that (in Win7)?

The image file is of .jpg format. I know how to change it into different image types, if that will help.

Comment: Um . . . why would you want to do that?

Comment: Erm, see. I am using Steganography to 'hide' a file within another file, in this case an Image. But the problem is, the Image is smaller than the file, so my Steganographic Software couldnt hide my file in the Image.

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate the image by artificially adding noise to it, so it wont distort the image, but give it more size. I believe this can be done in Photoshop, but I am not sure.